# XPATH inside IMPORTXML: how to find text in all languages?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to find all mentions of a Google Sheets' cell value on some website page. The cell value can be written in any language. The website page can also be in any language.

Now I have this formula:

`=COUNTA(IFERROR(IMPORTXML(A2;"//*[contains(translate(text(),'ABCDEFGHJIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZАБВГДЕЁЖЗИКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЭЮЯ', 'abcdefghjiklmnopqrstuvwxyzабвгдеёжзиклмнопрстуфхцчшщэюя'),'"&LOWER(B2)&"')]")))`

But it works incorrectly. It's not possible to find all words in Latin and Cyrillic, characters from Portuguese, German and other languages ​​are not taken into account. How to make the formula universal? Or how can I write the appropriate script for Google Sheets?

My formula works incorrectly. I want to find any text in any language on website page with Google Sheets' formula or script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could solve this more elegantly if Google Docs would support Xpath 2.0 and we could use the [`fn:lower-case()`](https://www.data2type.de/en/xml-xslt-xslfo/xslt/xslt-xpath-function-reference/alphabetical-xslt-and-xpath-reference/lower-case). In Xpath 1.0 we are stuck with `translate()` and need to provide the upper-case and lower-case translation ourselves. However, it is difficult to cover all possible (Unicode) characters in all languages this way.<sup>[1](https://doccookbook.sourceforge.net/html/en/dbc.common.case.html)</sup> I have added the diacritics from the Latin alphabet to your formula, which should cover most Western languages.

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(IMPORTXML(A2;"//*[contains(translate(text(),
'ABCDEFGHJIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞŸŽŠŒАБВГДЕЁЖЗИКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЭЮЯ', 
'abcdefghjiklmnopqrstuvwxyzàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿžšœабвгдеёжзиклмнопрстуфхцчшщэюя'),'"&LOWER(B2)&"')]")))
```

---

<sup>[1](https://doccookbook.sourceforge.net/html/en/dbc.common.case.html)</sup>: Furthermore, such a transformation does not work perfectly for all languages, e.g., the German 'ß' (lowercase) may be written as 'SS' when in uppercase which makes it difficult to find all matches.

Comment: Thank you. So, there is no way do something better through a script, am I right?

Comment: @MonteCristo I am unaware of built-in support for XPath queries in Google App Scripts.